# Vaadin - Height of textarea inside a tabsheet that is inside a splitpanel

Tags: java, layout, vaadin

I have a textarea inside a tabsheet, that is inside a splitepanel. My problem is that the textarea not fills the hole space in tabsheet. I have set all component with a height of 100%...but it doesn't work :(

Here is a screenshot of the tab
[image]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your HTML/CSS from here, but usually Vaadin adds some divs around elements - in this case, the text area - Try to inspect that parent(s) element of the text area and there has to be one of them that needs a 100%

Comment: I forgot to set the height of the tabsheet... argh!!...Thanks!